# Is there any way to control the time delay for a semantic-ui popup?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, css, typescript

The popup is appearing very fast.

The requirement is to show the popup after one second.

Comment: Could you please provide your code what you have tried

Comment: I have used it from https://semantic-ui.com/modules/popup.html#transitions.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take the [tour] of the site to understand how stackoverflow works and how to ask good  questions. Then come back and [edit] your question. Include the code of what you've tried as a [mcve], plus any error messages. Ask specific questions. Most people are happy to help, but don't want to do your work for you. Questions like "how do I do x?" that don't show any research effort on your end are likely to get ignored.

Answer (score 1):

You can use delay property like this

```
$('.example .menu .browse')
  .popup({
    inline     : true,
    hoverable  : true,
    position   : 'bottom left',
    delay: {
      show: 300,
      hide: 800
    }
  })
;
```

https://semantic-ui.com/modules/popup.html#/examples

Answer (score 0):

If your working with javascript or better yet, jquery, simply add a `.delay(1000);` to it.  This will delay the function by precisely `1 second` (1000 milliseconds = 1 second) which meets your requirement.

Or, you could try using a `setTimeout()` or `setInterval()`

This should get you on the right track...